# Forbidden Attributes Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Market is a model with a markets table with 3 columns: Name, created_at, and updated_at. I am trying to build a simple admin market index view where I can use a text field to create a market. I thought I had set up the market_params appropriately, but apparently I'm doing something wrong, because I get a Forbidden AttribuesError in MarketsController#create, and it highlights this line:

```
@market = Market.new(params[:market])
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

here is my markets controller:

```
class MarketsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @markets = Market.all
        @market = Market.new
    end

    def create
    @market = Market.new(params[:market])
    if @market.save
        flash[:success] = "Market Created!"
        render 'markets/index'
    else
        render 'markets/index'
    end
end


private
def market_params
    params.require(:market).permit(:name)
end
end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@market) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.text_area :name, placeholder: "Enter Market name here" %> 
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why?   ForbittionAttributError**

*Rails wont allow direct database create or update operations without whitelisting params. You have written method called market_params which does that but you are not using it.You are directly using params[:market] in new method.*

Change this line

> @market = Market.new(params[:market])

To

> @market = Market.new(market_params)

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're trying to create a market from `params[:market]`. Assuming you're using `strong_parameters`, you need to do this instead:

```
@market = Market.new(market_params)
```